# Chartjs - resize an image positioned in a column

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, chart.js

I successfully inserted an image within a column, and
I want to modify the width and the height of the image positioned on the column

**The question is:**

How can I access a canvaspattern height and width?.

If there is no way, what other approaches are there to position an image within a column?
-Other than amcharts-.

**Here is the code**:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = document.getElementById('image').src;
img.onload = function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var fillPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'no-repeat');

var chartData = {
  datasets : 
  [{
    label: 'user1',
    backgroundColor:'rgba(229,204,255,1)' ,
    data : [150]
  },
  {
    label: 'user2',
    backgroundColor: fillPattern,  
    data: [120]
    
  }
   ]
};

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        options:options
 });
};
```

**The output:**

part of the left of the image is just shown on the bar:
[image: part of the left of the image is just shown on the bar]

**the picture:**

[apple.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/556XZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels) to add images of desired size inside individual bars.

Please have a look at the code below.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [500, 450],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      labels: {
        render: 'image',
        textMargin: -160,
        images: [
          null,
          {
            src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/556XZ.png',
            width: 150,
            height: 150            
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: it is exactly what I've looked for, thank you for the effort !!